# How to convert a std::string containing bytes encoded in windows-1252 to a string containing utf8 encoded data?

Tags: c++, stl, character-encoding, node-addon-api, node-api

Using modern C++ and the std library, what is the easiest and cleanest way to convert a `std::string` containing `windows-1252` encoded characters to `utf-8`?

My use case is I'm parsing a CSV files which is `windows-1252` encoded, and then push some of its data to node-js using Node-Api (node-addon-api), which requires [`UTF-8` encoded strings](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/blob/main/doc/string.md).

Answer (score 0):

Using just the standard library, the closest solution would probably be to use `std::wstring_convert` with a custom Windows-1252 facet to convert the `std::string` to a `std::wstring`, and then use `std::wstring_convert` with a standard UTF-8 facet to convert the `std::wstring` to a `std::string`.

However, `std::wstring_convert` is deprecated since C++17, with no replacement in sight. So you are better off using a 3rd-party Unicode library to handle the conversion, such as iconv, ICU, etc. Or platform-specific APIs, like `MultiByteToWideChar()` and `WideCharToMultiByte()` on Windows, etc.

Or, you could simply implement the conversion yourself, since [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) is a very simple encoding, it has only 251 characters defined. A trivial lookup table to convert each 8bit character to its UTF-8 equivalent would suffice.